# How to have a screen intermittently render in React Native (with Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm building a React Native (with Expo) app and have a survey form screen that I want to have appear intermittently for the user to fill out. Let's call it `SurveyScreen`.  I'm doing this by setting a `setInterval` to poll the backend server hourly for scheduling data to see if the user is due to fill out a survey.  This will probably be done in the main App.js in `componentDidMount`

The above seems straightforward to me.  What I'm not clear on is once the polling api determines that the user is due for a survey, how to have the app display `SurveyScreen` no matter what page the user is on in the app.

One point of clarification is should `SurveyScreen` appear immediately after receiving a green light api response or should the screen appear after the next user action, e.g. navigation to another page, tap a button, etc? I think either way would be fine at this point.  Would love to know both ways if possible.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think you can go with mixture of both approaches like for example Now a days you might have seen that once you reach to the end of the page a popup appears from the bottom right to ask to the feedback related to the page. So in the similar manner you can implement your SurveyScreen also. Here user action will be scrolling to the bottom of the page/either navigation and also submitting the survey and getting the response from the api that whether to display it on another screen or not..

Comment: hey there , it would be easy to understand if you tell us what kind of app it is, educational, e-commerce or etc. will suggest accrodingly

Answer (score 0):

Update the state.

Example: you subscribe to api => event fires => you update state => survey pops up

You can use portal to easily position survey on top of everything.

Comment: Thanks. That would work if I implemented on every screen in the app.  Ideally, I'm looking for a solution where I would implement in one place, probably the root component App.js and it would work for all screens and any future screens I add.